# I need help with redirects

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, dns

There is a page with two domains:
`www.exampleone.com`
`www.exampletwo.com`

I need a redirect to the start page:
`www.exampleone.com` to `www.exampleone.com/#!/news.html`
`www.exampletwo.com` to `www.exampletwo.com/#!/news.html`

and last but not least, for **every page** I need a redirect like this, e.g.: `www.exampleone.com/about.html` to `www.exampleone.com/#!/about.html`
`www.exampletwo.com/about.html` to `www.exampletwo.com/#!/about.html`

I don't really know how to solve that, should I use Javascript or .htaccess? for the last redirect in my example, it's better to use conditions right? but how?

any ideas?

Note: The contents are loaded with ajax, so the index page is always the same, that why the `/#!/...` thing.

EDIT: straightforward, there are the live addresses http://www.jester04.ch or http://www.jester04baden.ch, the startpage redirect is solved as you can see in the js file, but for the `/#!/` redirects I still need help, thank you.

Comment: what are you currently using to handle your shebang (#!) URLs in JS to load the page via ajax?  I would imagine you could put something in that to handle the redirect when one doesn't exist.

Comment: @ben: the shebang is because of the [google ajax crawling method](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html), for the support of bookmark and history I use the jQuery address plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this block of JS code inside separate `.js` file then include this file in every page:

```
var sURL = (window.location.href + "").replace("http://", "");
if (sURL.indexOf("/#!/") < 0) {
   if (sURL.substr(sURL.length - 1, 1) == "/")
       sURL = sURL.substr(0, sURL.length - 1);
   var arrTemp = sURL.split("/");
   var sDomain = arrTemp[0];
   var sPage = (arrTemp.length > 1) ? arrTemp[arrTemp.length - 1] : "news.html";
   var sNewUrl = sDomain + "/#!/";
   for (var i = 1; i < arrTemp.length - 1; i++)
      sNewUrl += arrTemp[i] + "/";
   sNewUrl += sPage;
   window.location.href = "http://" + sNewUrl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but unfortunely it wont work. when I type `http://exampleone.com` the redirects goes like this `http://localhost/#!//www.exampleone.com/` 
Can you explain the code a little bit please? Thank you.

Comment: @Thomasz yeah sorry forgot about the `http://` - fixed this now. The code is taking the current URL "as-is" and split it by the `/` character to find the domain (e.g. www.exampleone.com) then it constructs new URL using the domain, appending the `/#!/` part and adding the rest of the URL parts after that. One benefit is that it will preserve querystring data, not sure other solutions will do that.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, thank you for your effort, this one works very well! i've just one last request, when you go to the site with just the domain http://www.jester04.ch, the redirect to the startpage "de/news.html" unfortunately wont work, it appends the `/#!/` but nothing more. I'm trying to find out why...

Comment: @Thomasz weird, try adding such alert to debug this and let me know the results: `alert(sNewUrl);`

Comment: `alert(sNewUrl);` gives `jester04.ch/#!/`  
-
`alert(sPage);` gives nothing!

Comment: @Thomasz what about `alert(sURL);'`? I believe the URL is ending with a `/` but want to be sure first.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard yes, `alert(sURL);` gives `jester04.ch/`

Comment: Redirecting with Javascript is definitely not the best way. If you want to have a seamless redirect, use the .htaccess options below. Javascript is a client side language and redirecting traffic with it doesn't make any sense. HTACCESS is built specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard well done man;) now it's exactly what i'm searchin' for, thanks a lot! what was the trick?

@Max Felker yes you're right, but I guess in this case with this requirements it's better to use javascript...

Comment: @Thomasz: as you can see in the code, I check if the URL is ending with `/` and in such case, remove it from the variable so it won't interfere.

Answer (score 3):

First I'd redirect both the homepages:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /#!/news.html [R,L]
```

Then all the other pages

```
RewriteRule (.*) /#!/$1 [R,L]
```

Didn't test it but this should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i'm searching for! but there is a problem with the `/#!/`, with your solution, it gives `http://exampleone.ch/%23!/news.html`, any idea?

Comment: @Thomasz, the # and after are never sent to the server, so this solution, will redirect any initial requests to http://exampleone.ch/#!/whatever to http://exampleone.ch/#!/news.html

Comment: @ben: yes you're right. But the page's content is loaded with ajax, there will never be a reload in browser (except the first certainly). with the hash fragment i'm saying, which page should be loaded in with ajax. This solution form Stephan Muller will work, the only problem is, the `#`sign will not correctly displayed, must be a encoding issue or something...

Comment: @Thomasz, someone doing a full refresh would mean that they'd get redirected back to the news.html one, rather than the one they are currently on.  Though to correct Stephan's rules change the [R,L] in both rules to [R,L,NE]

Comment: Nice one Ben, never heard of that flag before but it seems to work

Comment: @ben: Ok, now the url seems to be correct but Firefox says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." You know why?

Comment: @Thomasz, Firefox has seen that this will get into an infinite loop situation. as a server doing a redirect from / to /#!/news.html, will mean the browser will need to still try to fetch / (because as I mentioned in my first comment, the # and everything after is not sent to the server). I think the solution can only be handled in javascript. Is the site live at the moment? are you able to link to it? so we can see what code you have there already?

Comment: @ben: yes off course, short and straightforward: http://jester04.ch or http://jester04baden.ch, the redirect solution right now is with javascript, as you can see in the top of the js file, and there is only the redirect to startpage issue solved. thak you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.exampleone.com/#!/news.html

redirect 301 /about.html http://www.exampleone.com/#!/about.html
```

same for exampletwo.com

Put this in a .htaccess file in the root folder.